# How to write to a text file in VBScript, without overwriting?

Tags: vbscript

I am currently writing a script which parses the ServiceTage, Computername and Username from a computer and outputs it to a text file on a share, but it seems that it always overwrites the data there rather than adding to it.

The code is as follows:

```
'Get Dell Service Tag Info
set ProSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_BIOS")
Set ProSet1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_SystemEnclosure")
For each Pro in ProSet
  For each Pro1 in ProSet1
    ServiceTag=Pro.SerialNumber
    exit for
  Next
  exit for
Next

'get username and computername, could also be asked in a batch
Set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShellEnv  = oShell.Environment("Process")
sComputerName  = oShellEnv("ComputerName")
sUsername      = oShellEnv("username")

dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile("\\xx.xx.xx.xx\Support\DataLog.txt", 8, True)
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("\\xx.xx.xx.xx\Support\DataLog.txt")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
filetxt.WriteLine sUsername & ", " & sComputerName & ", " & ServiceTag
filetxt.Close
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the VBScript Docs:

```
object.CreateTextFile(filename[, overwrite[, unicode]])

object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
```

From your code:

```
Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile(filename, 8, True)
```

Diagnosis:

You call .CreateTextFile() with the parameters of .OpenTextFile()

Remedy:

Use .OpenTextFile():

```
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, True)
```

Comment: This may sound funny, but this worked - except this started writing in Chinese or Korean characters.

Comment: This sounds like you are writing in Unicode format/encoding; this feature is controlled by the fourth parameter to .OpenTextFile(). (See the Docs). Second thought: Did you delete the file created by the former .CreateTextFile() call?

Comment: I have change the format parameter to a "-2", which worked. But when looking at your second idea, I did not delete it and I believe that caused the problem. Thank you so much.