# How do i find all files starting with specific string or name in a directory in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

Hi, I have been looking for a solution that will look for some files in a directory.
Lets say my directory is : **"C:\temp\Result\"**. In the result folder there are 6 or more files:

```
File 1: "aaa.eee.txt"
File 2: "aaa.bbb.txt"
File 3: "aaa.ccc.txt"
File 4: "kkk.text"
File 5: "hhhh.xml"
File 6: "jjj.dll"
```

Now i need those files which name are started with **"aaa."**. Please help me out.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Anick, in this Forum you'll get help when you are stuck with your programming attempts - this means that you have to show at least basic understanding of programming, best by adding some code of your attempts in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each File In .GetFolder("c:\temp\result").Files
        If StrComp(Left(File.Name, 3), "aaa", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Do what you want with this file
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: '' If i would like to transfer each file name starting with "aaa" in logfile?

Comment: You want to copy the file to another location?

Comment: My need is find those files what ever started with"aaa" then copy the name of those files than write the log that you have found these files in this directory.

Comment: Using the code above, `File.Name` or `File.Path` can be used to return the file's name or complete path, respectively. To write to a text file, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124321/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-in-vbscript-without-overwriting/11125221#11125221) post.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I'll try this. if i can't make it happen i'll get back with you. Thanks appreciate you time and concern.